# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the possible cause of this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

My target framework is `netcoreapp2.1`.

This is my user store class:

```
public class MyUserStore : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And my user role class:

```
public class MyUserRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUserStore,MyUserRole,string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
      options): base(options) { }
}
```

My `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddIdentity<MyUserStore, MyUserRole>(cfg => {
        cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient<Seeder>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

i want to understand why this is happening and what is the best practice.

Comment: When does the exception throw? There is a "Seeder" service referenced. Do you possibly inject `UserManager<IdentityUser>` there, instead of `UserManager<MyUserStore>`, or in any other controller?

Comment: I fixed this by changing the references to `IdentityUser`in my view to `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Thanks @Fred changing to the name of my custom IdentityUser class worked (i.e. CGHIdentityUser : IdentityUser).  Specificaly, this had to be changed in _LoginPartial.cshtml -                                                 SignInManager<CGHIdentityUser> SignInManager
UserManager<CGHIdentityUser> UserManager

Comment: What file did you have to change @Fred I having the same issues.

Comment: @rogue39nin This was in /Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This usually happens in the **_LoginPartial.cshtml** or **_ManageNav.cshtml** razor view. Eg.

```
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
```

Must be changed to

```
@inject UserManager<MyUserStore> userManager
```

The same applies to `SignInManager`.

When registering your own `MyUserStore` (bad name, should be MyUser) for the AspNetCore Identity, the UserManager<> type will be registered to the ServiceCollection as `UserManager<MyUserStore>`.

**Whenever you want to resolve the `UserManager<>`, specify the identity user model registered in your startup as the type parameter.** Which would be `UserManager<MyUserStore>` in your specific case:

Or like-wise, when resolving it inside other classes, as may be the case in your `Seeder` service. The call stack of your exception should give you a hint of where this is happening.

Comment: Tried it. but still not working ....this is it on git   https://github.com/tizah/LeavePlannerApp2

Comment: @DavidZagi I literally changed [these](https://github.com/tizah/LeavePlannerApp2/blob/master/LeavePlannerApp2/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L3-L4) two lines to your identity user model and the the page loads perfectly fine

Comment: thanks @InDiaTasten. its working now. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yup the LoginPartial was still referencing the default IdentityUser

Comment: As I understand this means you have to replace lots of references (60+) in your scaffolded Identity pages. In addition, there is virtually no possibility to get these values in your startup/DI code without using async methods. Therefore I'd highly recommend using Claims for such additional fields instead and leave `IdentityUser`alone.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer You don't have to manually replace the references.Visual studio lets you specify a user class where you'll be asked to specify your data context class when scaffolding.

Answer (score 75):

In `_LoginPartial.cshtml`,
replace

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IndentityUser> UserManager
```

with

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<MyUserStore> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<MyUserStore> UserManager
```

Notice the difference, IdentityUser vs MyUserStore

Comment: Replacing `IdentityUser` with `MyUserStore` is incorrect; the error will still get thrown. `IdentityUser` has to be replaced with `ApplicationUser` (a derived class of the `IdentityUser` class as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-user-class)).

Comment: @somethingRandom In OP's case, this answer is correct, as he called his "ApplicationUser" MyUseStore instead. That's why my answer is more elaborate. The model name, as bad as it might be, just needs to match what was registered to the service collection in Startup.cs.

Answer (score 21):

Had same issue with core 2. One more area where you need to check is the file `_ManageNav.cshtml`. Try updating the line

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
```

with

```
@inject SignInManager<YOURCUSTOMMODEL> SignInManager
```

Comment: Missing other item `@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager`

Answer (score 4):

On the _ManageNav.cshtml file make sure you have the following:

```
@using PROJECTNAME.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
```

Please change PROJECTNAME to the name of your project.

Answer (score 4):

Got same error in a partial view.
Turns out if you are injecting sign in manager , you will have to register it in Configure Services (in Startup.cs/ in Program.cs in .Net 6)

In my case added this in ConfigureServices function in Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 2):

add below code in your Startup.cs or IdentityHostingStartup.cs file

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must also change the code here

> **\Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
> @inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager @inject
> UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

With

```
> @inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager @inject
> UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and `_ManageNav.cshtml` are necessary, but insufficient. I found dozens of other callsites which needed to be updated across many files.

The easiest approach is to use global search and replace <kbd>ctrl + shift + h</kbd>:

- search and replace `<IdentityUser>` with `<MyUser>`
- if using "default Identity UI" then search and replace `(IdentityUser user)` with `(MyUser user)`
- build
- there will be many errors (`The type or namespace name 'MyUser' could not be found...`); open each file and add the necessary `using ...` statement
- check changes before committing to source control (ensure you didn't replace something unrelated)