# Asp.net Core 3.1 startup AddIdentity Proplem (No service for type '.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I have added this code

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@.";
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<Services.IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, SmsSender>();
```

to my startup.cs "ConfigureServices" function to change password requirements , but i got error :"No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered" , so what is wrong with my code?

here is "ConfigureServices" function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    //        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@.";
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<Services.IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, SmsSender>();


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

also i have removed (commented) "AddDefaultIdentity" , you can see this at  "ConfigureServices" function section

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Are you trying to inject/resolve `UserManager<IdentityUser>` somewhere? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne

Comment: Try use `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Thanks alot ... ihave solved this issue... and i will publish my answer, your comments was helpful