# How to add new userId roleId to AspNetUserRoles Table and remove a row from AspNetUserRoles Table?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to add new userID and roleId to `AspNetUserRoles` Table.
I searched about it, but still didn't get a correct answer.

`AspNetUserRoles` Table is something like this.

```
|userId | roleId |
|abc-12 | 1      |
|abc-12 | 2      |
|dcs_32 | 2      |
```

How can create new object of `AspNetUserRoles` and add new new `userID` and `roleId` to `AspNetUserRoles` Table and remove a row from `AspNetUserRoles` Table?

Comment: It's better to use UserManager methods than SQL. Do you need SQL?

Comment: no I need UserManager methods

Answer (score 1):

Look at the base methods from Microsoft Identity framework.

Like:

```cs
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
```

The UserManager exposes all the methods you required.

Comment: Thankyou so much.How to remove from AspNetUserRoles Table? Do you have any idea?

Comment: `How to remove from AspNetUserRoles Table?` You can call [`RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser, String)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.removefromroleasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_RemoveFromRoleAsync__0_System_String_) to remove the specified user from the named role.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create roles you have to use RoleManager.
There is method CreateAsync(IdentityRole).

In order to assing role to user, you have to use UserManager.
There is method AddToRoleAsync(IdentityUser, role).

Both class are members of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

```
 private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
 private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _rolemanager;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the official Identity, you will have the following database tables.

- AspNetUsers
- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserRoles
- ...

They maybe create by below command

```
dotnet new webapp --auth Individual -o WebApp1
```

If you want to modify some thing, like login page layout, you will need [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If you want change those tables field, you need this [Customize the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-model).

After add your self custom user and role, the place where IdentityUser was used before must be modified.

```
UserManager<IdentityUser>
```

Need change to

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

ApplicationUser is your custom user model

If you didn't change, will show this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne?fbclid=IwAR3PzwDljeF_86qQOl-0pm0oIqgu0J2JC-93jA-6g08zFnExBxg4BdeXEBw).

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]’ has been registered.