# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[ABC_App.Repository.Models.ApplicationUser]' has been registered

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

As per my project requirements, I have to keep four different projects in the same solution running on different ports.

Following is the current structure of my solution:

1. Asp.Net Core 5.0 Web API Project (Which uses repository pattern for CRUD operations in response to Client Application's requests)
2. Asp.Net Core 5.0 Web Application Project For Admin Users (Client-Side)
3. Asp.Net Core 5.0 Web Application Project For Super Admin (Client-Side)
4. Asp.Net Core 5.0 Class Library (For Repository Pattern)

As per this structure, I have to allow both Super Admin and Admin Users to be authenticated and authorized by Identity. However, I am facing problems in implementing Identity the correct way.

Until now, I have done the following:

1. Created `ApplicationContext.s` Class within Repository Project and inherited it from `IdentityDbContext`.
2. Run initial migration with update-database script which results in creating Identity Tables in my database.
3. Created custom class for users, named it `ApplicationUser.cs`, and inherited it from `IdentityUser` class with custom fields for the first name, last name, and company name.
4. Because I had to create both Client Applications (Admin and Super Admin Portals) with no authentication option, so I added the Identity Scaffolding using CMD and the Identity is successfully scaffolded (For now, only on Super Admin Portal).
5. Have replaced the `IdentityUser` class with my custom `ApplicationUser.cs` class everywhere in my application.
6. Because I have to use the `ApplicationContext.cs` class of Repository Project for database operations, so I have configured the `startup.cs` class of my API Project such that it will use the `ApplicationContext.cs` class from Repository Project while I have set up the connection string within the `appsettings.json` file of this (The API) Project.
7. And have removed everything related to the `ApplicationContext.cs` class setup from the `startup.cs` class of my Super Admin Project, because the purpose of doing this is already mentioned, I do want to use the `ApplicationContext.cs` class of Repository Project within the API Project.
8. And because I have added the Identity Scaffolding to my API Project which created the `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` class within Areas > Identity Folder, so I moved the `ApplicationContext.cs` setup and Identity Injection as a service to this newly created `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` class.

The Configure Method of `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` class now looks like this:

```
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

                 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                    .AddDefaultUI();
            });
        }
```

9. And as per my continuous research for resolving this issue, I modified the `ApplicationContext.cs` class of my Repository Project and it now looks like this:

   ```
   public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole, string>
   {
         public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
         {
         }
   }
   ```
10. And when I run the application, I am getting the following error on the Super Admin Page:

`No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[ABC_App.Repository.Models.ApplicationUser]' has been registered`

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context) Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator<TContext>.Activate(object instance, TContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(object page, ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, object model, IView view) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count) AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__69_1() Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync() AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync() Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters() Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

Looks like I am missing something in setting up the identity classes within `ApplicationContext.cs` or I am doing the identity scaffolding the wrong way. Because the same `ApplicationContext.cs` class is working fine on the Admin Portal Project and is allowing user to communicate with the API Project for database operations.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This usually happens in the _LoginPartial.cshtml razor view.You can check this post, it may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne

Comment: @Chaodeng Yes, you are right. The error is appearing in my case when I comment <partial name="_LoginPartial" /> on my _Layout.cshtml file. I am still looking for the reason that why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Boom. I solved the problem. It was my mistake that I was completely avoiding the `startup.cs` class of Super Admin portal. I thought that each application will be using the `startup.cs` class of API Project.

I included the following code in ConfigureServices method on my Admin Portal's `startup.cs` class and the issue was resolved:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();
```