# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext' has been registered

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

While using the "AddIdentity" Extension Method i got the Error: `'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext' has been registered.'`

I added the `IdentityUser` to a `ApplicationUser` class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { }
```

Then i have configured the DbContext:

```
public class ReadDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<FileReadModel> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryReadModel> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");
        var configuration = new ReadConfiguration();
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<FileReadModel>(configuration);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<CategoryReadModel>(configuration);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And finally calling the `AddIdentity` Extension Method.

```
var options = configuration.GetOptions<PostgresOptions>("Database");
services.AddDbContext<ReadDbContext>(ctx =>
            ctx.UseNpgsql(options.ConnectionString));
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ReadDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But at Startup I get the Error that the service type for **IdentityDbContext** could not be found. I tried to configure custom Roles and custom keys as well. I get the same error every time. What am I missing here?

Comment: *the service type for IdentityDbContext could not be found* - show us your full DI registration code (the block of code in startup that is all AddScoped/AddTransient/AddDb../AddThis/AddThat); it seems like you've forgotten to AddDbContext your IdentityDbContext? Something is calling for the DI to provide an instance of an IdentityDbContext and the injector doesn't know what it is

Comment: I edited the question and added the relevant parts, i did already register the DbContext. I would add that i now just want to extend my already existing and working DbContext with `IdentityDbContext` and `ApplicationUser`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager\`1\[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser\]' has been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne)

Answer (score 0):

In somewhere you are going to inject wrong class,

as an example ;

```
@inject ManagerClass<IdentityDbContext> managerClass
```

to

```
@inject ManagerClass<ApplicationUser> managerClass
```

Comment: No currently I do not inject the class at any point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Something could not be cleanly removed from the `bin` or `object` folder. A cleanup did nothing, but manually deleting the compiled files did. After removing it runs with recompilation!