# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[testLogin.Areas.Identity.Data.testLoginUser]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'd like to know what is the possible issue for this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[testLogin.Areas.Identity.Data.testLoginUser]' has been registered.
```

I'm working on .net6

I've already look through this [No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne) and tried to apply changes but it doesn't work either.

Here is my User class :

```
public class testLoginUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using testLogin.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<testLoginUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<testLoginUser> UserManager
```

I've been following a tutorial online and I was adapting it from the best I can to my current .net version, can someone tell me how I could imporve myself?

Comment: And what services are you trying to register?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have registered it in Configure Services:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Without registering it,you cannot inject it to your view.

Comment: Hi, I've did that previously but I'm still running into the same error

Comment: Can you share your startup.cs?

Comment: ```

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

```