# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered Using Custom Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I would like to register my service using the CustomUser class, which inherits from IdentityUser.

However, when I do I get the following error in my browser:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

My relevant code:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you change into `@inject UserManager<CustomUser> userManager` in your  _LoginPartial.cshtml or _ManageNav.cshtml razor view ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager\`1\[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser\]' has been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne)