# When I run the project the this error is appearing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Comment: Could you share  code of  your Program.cs ? Besides, you can check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne .