# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Error:**

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser]' has been registered.

I am a student and trying to understand why I am getting this error. I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution. I am using .Net 8.
Thank you.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using readiit.Areas.Identity.Data
@using readiit.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager\`1\[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser\]' has been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568264/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1microsoft-aspne)

Comment: `I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution` don't lie. Liars aren't welcome here.

Comment: @JoostMolenkamp No, I've updated my LoginPartial to use ApplicationUser and still am getting this error.

Comment: @IanKemp what's the point of this comment

Comment: You are using your own `ApplicationUser` right? So that shall we replace all the `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`? Maybe we need to modify `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` right? Then here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68692347/14574199) in the link @IanKemp shared. He think this is a common issue so that you should find the solution instead of saying `looked everywhere and cannot find a solution`. I can understand you because I'm a  beginner as well : )

Comment: Is there any process in this question? whether you got the error resolved? @bee

Answer (score 0):

Reproducing the issue by only changing `ApplicationUser` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

[image]

Then update Program.cs `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` with `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`.

And you'd **better to search in your project or follow the error message to see if you still have somewhere else using `IdentityUser`**, replace them with `ApplicationUser`. Like you see, I already changed my Program.cs but I faced this issue when I click the sign in button on the page.

[image]